# Use of preposition to or of?

Tags: prepositions

The sentence

> The company holds the show's licence.

when we paraphrase, we use

> The company holds the licence **to** the show

not *'the licence **of** the show'* (or perhaps you do? please also discuss on this)

I found these kind of usage on some other occasions.

So, how do we determine whether to use ***to*** or ***of*** when we wants to say ***something's***

Also, what would you use here?

*'the rights of distribution'* or *'the rights to distribution'*

Thank you for your time.

Comment: These words *can* mean the same thing but also there is a connotation that *to* is often something smaller and *of* is often something more encompassing.  If I say that I have a ticket **to** a ballgame then I have a seat there and can watch; one of many tickets.  If I say I have a license **to** a ballgame then maybe I'm a vendor who has one of many licenses issued by that ballgame.  If I say I have something **of** a ballgame, like, say, a contract **of** a ballgame that implies something larger, more encompassing, like exclusive TV rights **of** the entire ballgame.

Comment: Expanding on prior comment, one could say ticket **to** a ballgame but ticket **of** a ballgame is not idiomatic; there is a limit when one is talking about only a very small part like a seat at a ballgame where one would only use **to** and not **of**.  For a contract **to/of** a ballgame for TV rights, either is idiomatic, but since **of** can only be used for something more encompassing like this, perhaps **of** would be preferred by some native speakers in a situation like this, and **to** for more specific, smaller situations like a seat.

Comment: If one were to speak of something really broad, like *I am the King of the entire World!* the only **of** works; in this case **to** is not idiomatic.  Basically **of** implies *the entire thing* and **to** implies *a part (from very small up to 100%) of a specific thing*, so one would generally say *I am the CEO **of** a business* (the entire business), *I am the President **of** the United State* (the entire USA), but *I have memberships **to** several book clubs* (one of many members to several specific book clubs).  You could also use **in** here - *in several book clubs*.

Comment: Raw Google results (which admittedly need careful interpretation) are 247 000 hits for "hold the licence for the" and 3 (including 2 false positives) for "hold the licence to the".